# Final Fantasy VII on PC - what does this have that my original discs don't?

Tags: version-differences, final-fantasy-7

I have got my original Playstation Final Fantasy VII discs in a box at home, and for the past 5 years have been meaning to go back and play the game but of course I never get around to it (at the weekend I just finished Dragon Quest VIII - obviously I have a backlog).
Having seen a few FFVII posts on here and noticing the sharper graphics I found it is available on PC:
http://www.finalfantasyviipc.com/en

what does this have that my original discs don't?

What are the differences over the original game? As far as I can see there are 36 "achievements" (?) and a "character booster" (one-click cheat mode which I'd not be interested in). It claims that all I need is an internet connection* to play wherever I am... surely I'd need to download it? Or is it all hosted in the cloud and I could play on my mobile phone?

*under Cloud Saves button - "Whether you’re away from home or simply using a different computer to play, enjoy FINAL FANTASY VII wherever you are. With cloud save support in FINAL FANTASY VII you can continue your game progress right where you left off, all you need is an internet connection."

Comment: Cloud saves are all well and good, but what this game really needs is some Aeris saves.

Comment: Unfortunately some people thinks this is a shopping recommendation which it is not. So I cannot answer my question.
I'm told that you can get FFVII on steam, but then can apply a mod to give it better graphics. So that is a benefit to playing the PC version over the original PS1 game.
Also, the SquareEnix one uses Securom (which you don't want).

Comment: @VictorySaber: I suspect the problem is your middle paragraph where you say "Is it worth me purchasing...". I'm not sure that the close reason given is quite right but you are adding subjectivity into your question which it doesn't really want. Focus it more on "What are the differences between the PC and PS versions of FFVII" and it is likely to be considered a much better question. Then use your own judgements of whether those differences are worth it to you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris. I think we all know what I'm asking - "what does this have that my original discs don't?". Actually that's better - I'll edit the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Whether it is worth it for you, only you can say. If you've not played it in the years you've had the discs sat at home, why would you play it now with a download version? It'd save you the hassle of having a Playstation set up, or an emulator -- but whether that's worth the price tag is something only you can decide.)*

The minimum system requirements on that site are:

- Microsoft Windows XP/Vista/7 (32/64-bit)
- 2GHz Processor or faster
- 1GB RAM
- DirectX 9-compatible graphic card

If you have an internet connection and a suitable PC, you can download the game again and play it from where you left off by taking advantage of the cloud save storage. You will not be able to play this version on your mobile phone. The "with just an internet connection" part is strictly talking about transferring save files between computers with the Square Enix Cloud Save function.

Finally, this version is the same as that [found on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/39140/). If you already use Steam, then it may be preferable for you to buy it from there.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the internet connection quote.
I too am thinking I'd need to download the game again, but that quote makes me wonder if it is hosted. For example Twitch plays Pokemon, you have a view on the game and an interface without any downloading.

Comment: Ok, yes... that's only talking about the cloud-save functionality.

Comment: The game would sit on your local PC (just as it did back in '97 with the initial PC port). Just keep in mind that you won't get around setting up and using a "Square Enix Account" - no matter whether you buy the Steam version or the non-Steam one. Both use Square's account system as some kind of added DRM (plus it provides that bought booster functionality).